# Trouble bringing in CloudWatch data to Logstash

Tags: logstash, elk

Just getting started with a new ELK setup (never used it before, just trying to learn it).  I have Logstash 2.2.4 running on ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

After putting a yaml file down with my monitor user's AWS credentials (policy configured as per the documentation via copy/paste), I created the following .conf file in /etc/logstash/conf.d:

```
input {
  cloudwatch {
   metrics => ["CPUUtilization"]
   filters => { "tag:Monitoring" => "Yes" }
   region => "us-east-1"
   namespace => "AWS/EC2"
   aws_credentials_file => "/var/opt/aws.yaml"
  }
}
output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
  }
}
```

I have three servers in us-east-1 with the tag "Monitoring" set to "Yes", but when I tail my logstash logs it is erroring out that there are no metrics to query.  An example error entry (formatted for readability):

```
{
  :timestamp=>"2016-10-31T13:38:06.314000-0400", 
  :message=>"A plugin had an unrecoverable error. Will restart this plugin.\n  
  Plugin: <LogStash::Inputs::CloudWatch 
              metrics=>[\"CPUUtilization\"], 
              filters=>{\"tag:Monitoring\"=>\"Yes\"}, 
              region=>\"us-east-1\", 
              namespace=>\"AWS/EC2\",  
              aws_credentials_file=>\"/var/opt/aws.yaml\", 
              codec=><LogStash::Codecs::Plain charset=>\"UTF-8\">, 
                     use_ssl=>true, 
                     statistics=>[\"SampleCount\", \"Average\", \"Minimum\", \"Maximum\", \"Sum\"], 
                     interval=>900, 
                     period=>300, 
                     combined=>false>\n  Error: No metrics to query", :level=>:error}
```

*EDIT*

Based on the comment, I updated my policy for the service user whose credentials are in the above mentioned .yaml file. This did not change the behavior, here is what my policy currently looks like:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1444715676000",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "cloudwatch:GetMetricStatistics",
                "cloudwatch:ListMetrics"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1444716576170",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:DescribeInstances",
                "ec2:DescribeTags"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

In checking that I had actually assigned the policy to the user correctly, I noticed that at some point in debugging I *also* assigned the 'CloudWatchReadOnlyAccess' policy, which looks like this (in case it breaks something):

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Action": [
        "autoscaling:Describe*",
        "cloudwatch:Describe*",
        "cloudwatch:Get*",
        "cloudwatch:List*",
        "logs:Get*",
        "logs:Describe*",
        "logs:TestMetricFilter",
        "sns:Get*",
        "sns:List*"
      ],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": "*"
    }
  ]
}
```

This is actually my first time using something other than the pre-defined policies, so I'm thinking perhaps I missed something in the writing of it.

Answer (score 2):

What they don't tell you in the documentation, is that you need to have some more rights set in order to use filters. The code performs a [describe-instances](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/describe-instances.html) call on your account, using the `filters` to get a list of instance-ID's, which it then runs the cloudwatch API calls on.

The IAM policy listed in the documentation only covers the cloudwatch API calls. If you left off filters entirely in your config, [you'd get data](https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-input-cloudwatch/issues/9).

However, you want to filter on tags. For that, you'll need at least:

```
ec2:DescribeInstances
ec2:DescribeTags
```

In an allow statement to be able to get the data you need.

To troubleshoot this, I would verify that the AWS credentials do what they should to rule that out. The AWS CLI equivalent of what they're doing is:

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --filters "Name=tag:Monitoring,Value=Yes"
```

If that fails, then this is your problem. You might need `ec2:DescribeNetworkInterfaces` as well, but I'm not certain of that.

If that succeeds, then the problem is not with your EC2 rights, its with something else. You can replicate the call the plugin is making to cloudwatch this way:

```
aws cloudwatch list-metrics --namespace AWS/EC2 --dimensions "Name=InstanceId,Value=i-1234abcd" --metric-name CPUUtilization
```

The plugin is using the `describe-instances` call to fetch the `InstanceId` values for instances with the Monitoring tag.

If this works, and so does the instance-fetching, then it is a problem with the plugin somehow. Verify that the credentials file is actually readable by the logstash process. You can bypass the need to search for tags by attempting to fetch a specific instance. [There is an example in the code](https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-input-cloudwatch/blob/master/lib/logstash/inputs/cloudwatch.rb#L106) for how to specify this.

```
filters => { 'instance-id' => 'i-1234abcd' }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  This was helpful, though it did not actually change the behavior in any way that I can tell. I've posted my policies that are assigned to the user in the question in case I've messed something up in there.

Comment: fwiw I also tried both removing my `filters` declaration and declaring it as an empty hash, and still didn't get data.

Comment: @Paul I updated my answer with a troubleshooting guide.

Comment: THanks, the troubleshooting guide is helping.  Running the describe-instances command, I get an error that "Proxy URLs must have explicit schemes."  I am behind a corporate proxy, but I don't see how that error is correct when I can observe my proxy settings include the http:// protocol prefix.  I'll dig into that, though.

Comment: OK, fixed my proxy issue (it was a problem), and can now do the aws calls myself via the CLI.  I've changed the path to the credentials file to be the one in my own home directory (~/.aws/credentials) which is what the CLI is using when I make the api call, and I verified that the access on ~/.aws/credentials is set to rw-r--r--, which as far as i know should be all I need to do in order to give the logstash user access to read them.